# Need help in string parsing?

Tags: php, parsing, string

I am creating SQL query based on user input:

```
// user input
$amount = '20';

// query in zend 
$select->where('amount = ?', $amount );
```

Now according to new requirements user can input in following formats as well:

```
$amount = '20';
$amount = '<20';
$amount = '<=20';
$amount = '>20';
$amount = '>=20';
$amount = '=20';
```

I think you understand the new feature. So how can I parse `$amount` variable to fit it in above query? I have to separate `number` and `sign` from `$amount` variable to use them on their proper position. And if there is wrong sign`(i.e  $amount='$%20'; )` then it should consider it as equal sign`(i.e  $amount='=20'; )`

What approach should I follow to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: first, assume all inputs are correct and rewrite `$select->where('amount = ?', $amount );` to `$select->where('amount  ?', $amount );`, does it solve your problem? if yes then you can find the integer values out of the input by using a small regex, some thing like '[0-9]*', strip off the input using the int values you have

Comment: Yes. But user can enter wrong sign(i.e $amount='$%20'; ) as described in my question.

Comment: can a user input arbitrary number of characters? Can I input a complete copy paste a complete web page in the input?

Comment: It will be always like (signs)(numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parts = array();
if (preg_match('/^(\D+)?(\d+)$/', $amount, $parts)) {
    $operator = (!in_array($parts[1], array('=', '<', '<=', '>=', '>'))) ? '=' : $parts[1];
    $value    = $parts[2];
    $select->where('amount ' . $operator . ' ?', $value );
}
```

Comment: +1 Much cleaner solution than mine. Why did I use a second regex when there is `in_array()` :).

Comment: Where are you setting value of `$parts[2]`. In 3rd line, there is no `$parts[2]`. Is it a typo ?

Comment: `$parts` contains 3 keys after the `preg_match` call. `0` is the whole match (not needed), `1` is the captured match from the first parenthesis pair and `2` is the captured match from the second parenthesis pair.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: Working perfectly.Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: There is a small problem. It is not working when there is a floating point number. For example: `>45.15` or `=10.00`. It was not included in my question. Sorry for that. Do you have a quick solution. Thanks

Comment: @Awan: Simple fix (but this may fail in some edge cases); change the regular expression to `/^(\D+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex to separate them:

```
preg_match('/(<|>|=|<=|>=)([0-9]+)/', $amount, $matches);
$sign=$matches[1];
$number=$matches[2];
```

---

**UPDATE:** I have tested this and found that it does not handle erroneous signs properly. I came up with the following code which seems to work fine:

```
$amount=">=20";
preg_match('/([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)/', $amount, $matches);
$sign=preg_match('/^(>|<|=|<=|>=)$/', $matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '=';
$number=$matches[2];
```

If the string given is `>=20` then sign is `>=` and number is '20', if the string given is '%$20' then sign is `=` and number is `20`.

Comment: will it take care of `%^$%^ 20`?

Comment: Alternatively, `/([<>]?=?)([0-9]+)/`

Comment: `$matches[0]` does not contain the operator but rather the complete match. The captured parts are in `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` respectively. Furthermore this doesn't cover the case where no operator is specified.

Comment: @Stefan Yes it was a typo. Updated my answer after testing my "solution". Now it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If user can specify operator with value you have to be careful. Try with:

```
$input = '<=20';
$allowedOperators = array('<', '<=', '>', '>=', '=');

if ( in_array(substr($input,0,2), $allowedOperators) ) {
    $operator = substr($input,0,2);
} else if ( in_array(substr($input,0,1), $allowedOperators) ) {
    $operator = substr($input,0,1);
} else {
    $operator = '=';
}

$amount = (int) substr($input, strlen($operator));

$select->where('amount ' . $operator . ' ?', $amount );
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is little bit long but flexible. I can add more options in `$allowedOperators` array in future. I will try this also.

Comment: There are some issues: I tried `$input=^&21` then output is `servicerecord.TotalFees = 0`. It should be `servicerecord.TotalFees = 21`